# How to debug/step through external/loaded swf - FlashProfessional?

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, flash, loader

(Flash Professional / AS3)

I have a main fla file that loads a game (with a Loader) and adds it to the stage (addChild(myLoader)).  Is there a way to step through/debug the loaded swf?  If so, how?  My game.swf breakpoints aren't hitting.

Comment: I don't think you can. If you could, it would be SO EASY to decompile swf files (just load them in another file and debug). Not to say that it is difficult to decompile it now :)

Comment: Not entriely sure if it will work in your case, but you could five [remote debugging](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WSD76536C2-C8AA-472a-BE2F-BD0D0855972Aa.html#WSCE33BC10-1F5A-4748-9EFF-641D89B18659a) a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you debug (Control > Debug Movie)  both files?

You need to debug both Main and Game to be able to get breakpoints in the loaded SWF to work. When you Debug a SWF, extra information is added to the file. If you just publish the file there will not be any debug info.

Comment: By debug he means building the swf with debug information ctrl+shift+enter will do that or you can change the publish settings to always include debug information.

Comment: Yes.  I did that.  Have you been able to get this to work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [MonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/).